# Android SDK setup in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt, eclipse-3.5

Which android sdk should be downloaded with eclipse galileo 3.5 version. and what ADT Plugin should be installed? i downloaded android sdk 1.6 and initially installed adt 0.7 plugin but it said adt needs to be updated. but now when im trying to update the adt to 16 it shoes the following error:
    Your original request has been modified.
    "Android Development Tools" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
    Software being installed: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534    (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Missing requirement: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0' but it could not be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

you can see ADT 16.0.0+ requires Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6), so I think you need ADT 15.0.1

Comment: cant find the adt 15.0.1 zip file. can u provide  alink for it

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick search i found this:

[how to install android sdk on eclipse 3.5](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/07/install-android-sdk-on-eclipse-35.html)

Answer (score 0):

You download the SDK for your OS.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
If you use windows, I recommend the exe file for you. 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: my os is windows 7 AG by ambala gurmeet. does the os has anything to do with the error?

Comment: there's some problem in eclipse update method, this is why your adt can not be updated. maybe you should try to delete everything what is related with the eclipse and reinstall everything (or try to delete the adt itself from eclipse and reinstall it)

Comment: thnx and how do i reinstall the plugin? i cant find the option anywhere

Comment: after remove, you can install it this way: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/
index.html.
Once the SDK is downloaded, unzip its content (the android-sdk-windows folder)
into the C:\Android\ folder, or whatever name you have given to the folder you just
created.

Once Eclipse is up and running, select the Help >> Install New Software
In the Install window that appears, type http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse in the text and click Add

Answer (score 0):

You may reinstall the eclipse by the following steps

1. Install jre7 with Netbeans
2. install eclipse
3. install ADT
4. in the step 3, you are asked to install Android SDK version by which package. click the top option