# Error in Installing Android sdk in eclipse galileo

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse Galileo IDE. Now I want to install Android Sdk.I get the following error while installing the Sdk.Can anyone suggest a solution?
The error is as follows:

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
Missing requirement: Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0' but it could not be found
```

Comment: Please click [**this**][1] link, it's helpful for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615048/android-sdk-setup-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Galileo is [no longer supported](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements). Update your Eclipse to Helios or newer.

You can download the ADT Bundle as suggested by Boris Strandjev.

Answer (score 3):

You are going with too old Eclipse. I would not be surprised if the newest SDKs are not compatible with it. I would suggest you to download the newest [Android Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) - it goes with sdk and Eclipse IDE packaged in one archive.

Here are [instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) how you will install it.